# How to deploy flutter app on iPhone without Apple Developer Account?

Tags: ios, flutter, deployment, apple-developer

I am developing an app with flutter for both android and iOS. I want to try it out on an actual iPhone before I can publish it.
But I don’t want to get a paid apple developer account just yet as I am not really confident with the app.
How can I deploy it on an actual iPhone without the account ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a paid Apple developer account... that's just for submitting things to the store.  With a free developer account, you can sign and install apps on your own devices **only**.

Comment: But is there any way to provide to users too? like uploading the apk to a website or making a download website from which users can download the app?

Comment: No.  If you're a paid developer, you can participate in TestFlight, and have a limited number of testers for your app, but your app would otherwise also have to qualify by the App Store standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use diawi:

1. Upload the iOS or Android application.
2. Send the link to your testers, clients, friends or even use it yourself.
3. Open the link in the browser on the device and click on install.